# Error Compiling any coding in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, compile, avr-gcc

I was using the example code of "Blink", and when I try to compile it, it pop out an error as below.

I tried to:

1. uninstall and installed back the Arduino IDE
2. installed different versions of Arduino IDE
3. update the u8glib library
4. installed different version of Arduino AVR boards

but still doesn't work.

> Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs
>   -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder -tools C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -tools
>   C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries -libraries
>   C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno
>   -vid-pid=0X2341_0X0043 -ide-version=10809 -build-path C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_109130 -warnings=none
>   -build-cache C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_111506 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr
>   -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr
>   -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr
>   -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr
>   -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr
>   -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose
>   C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\FSR\FSR.ino
>
> Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

Comment: reinstall Arduino IDE. better try 1.8.10